# Deferred stock update in Magento 2.1 CE - Stock not being updated?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Everything I have read says that deferred stock update is an EE feature, but the option is showing up in CE on the product advanced inventory control page (both for configurable products and the simple products under them). Changing the setting does not work. It is stuck on "Use Config Settings", which I can't find. It's not in the store config->catlog->inventory options.

This may be causing a problem and I'm try to track down where the stock is not being decreased after a purchase.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing the problems?

Answer (score 2):

After running tests on it for a few hours I figured out a fix. New products worked fine, but ones that were there before the update did not decrease in stock. They increased in stock if an order was canceled though. I ended up having to open each product and hit save.

It must be another bug in the updating. Something in the database changed, but existing items where not updated to the new format/with the new info.